# Saving State of Multiple Checkboxes - Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am able to save the state of a Single CheckBox but how do i save All the Five CheckBoxes in my Activity?

```
  checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
    Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
    checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
            Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
        }
    });
}
public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
    editor.commit();        
}
public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    return isChecked;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second checkbox do the following

```
 boolean isCheckedTwo = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedTwo");

        checkBox2.setChecked(isCheckedTwo );

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedTwo");
            }
        });
```

and similarly for the rest

Comment: Thanks it is working, do you know how to Check a CheckBox by Default?

Comment: you also set android:checked="true" in the xml also

Comment: already tried that, i tried both of the xml attributes but both don't work for me, so the java one works

Answer (score 0):

Use a Arraylist to store the state of all the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Put each one with different name. and remember the key comes first not the value. Call your save method each time with different name